# How to use refetchQueries with reason-apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, reason, reason-react

I'm using reason-apollo and having problems trying to setup `refetchQueries`. My setup is very similar to the swapi example [here](https://github.com/apollographql/reason-apollo/tree/master/examples/swapi). I have a listing and a form to add a new item via a mutation. After the mutation succeeds, I want to refetch the items in the listing. My code for creating a new item looks like this (skipping some of the irrelevant ui code):

```
module CreateFilm = [%graphql
  {|
  mutation createFilm($name: String!, $favourite: Boolean!, $rating: Int!, $ratedOn: DateTime!) {
      createFilm(name: $name, favourite: $favourite, rating: $rating, ratedOn: $ratedOn) {
          id
          favourite
          name
          rating
      }
  }
|}
];

module CreateFilmMutation = ReasonApollo.CreateMutation(CreateFilm);

type state = {
  favourite: bool,
  rating: int,
};

type action =
  | ToggleFavourite
  | UpdateRating(int);

let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("FilmNew");

let make = _children => {
  ...component,
  initialState: () => {favourite: true, rating: 5},
  reducer: action =>
    switch (action) {
    | ToggleFavourite => (
        state => ReasonReact.Update({...state, favourite: ! state.favourite})
      )
    | UpdateRating(newRating) => (
        state => ReasonReact.Update({...state, rating: newRating})
      )
    },
  render: ({state, send}) => {
    let now = Js.Date.make() |> Js.Date.toISOString |> Js.Json.string;
    let newFilm =
      CreateFilm.make(
        ~name="Temporary test",
        ~rating=state.rating,
        ~favourite=state.favourite,
        ~ratedOn=now,
        (),
      );
    <CreateFilmMutation>
      ...(
           (mutation, _result) =>
             <form
               onSubmit=(
                 event => {
                   ReactEventRe.Synthetic.preventDefault(event);
                   mutation(
                     ~refetchQueries=[|"allFilms"|],
                     ~variables=newFilm##variables,
                     (),
                   )
                   |> ignore;
                 }
               )>
               <input
                 className="toggle"
                 _type="checkbox"
                 checked=state.favourite
                 onChange=((_) => send(ToggleFavourite))
               />
               ("is favourite" |> ReasonReact.string)
               <input _type="submit" value="Submit" />
             </form>
         )
    </CreateFilmMutation>;
  },
};
```

The film gets successfully added and I can see it in the listing (which is using the `allFilms` query) when the page is refreshed. But `refetchQueries` does not seem to have any effect. My backend is using graph.cool, similar to the swapi example in the docs. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the mutation, but with the query I wanted to refetch - it was missing its graphql operation name ‍♂️